# Longest Loop in Graph

Tags: graph-theory, definition

Please consider the following graph:

[image]

Is there a formal definition for the longest nonrepeating sequence of vertices which form a loop in a graph? (**A, G, B, C, D, E, F**)

And how about the longest loop without shortcuts? (**A, B, C, D**)

The closest I'm aware of is the *Graph Diameter*, but that's obviously very different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you call "loop" is more commonly known as a [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)), and there doesn't seem to be any common term other than "longest cycle".

Your "loop without shortcuts" appears to be a [chordless cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#Chordless_cycles). Again, I don't think there's a commonly used nicer term than "longest chordless cycle".

Comment: Thank you! A search for "longest cycle" yields a [1975 Computer Science paper](https://github.com/augfrank/facebull/blob/master/papers/circuits_johnson.pdf) which calls the second problem "[longest] elementary circuit".